# Scala, Slick, Cats - How to map different SQL errors with OptionT?

Tags: scala, slick, scala-cats

I have a simple `slick` query which run on database:

```
def method(): Future[Either[Error, MyCustomDTO]] = 
OptionT(database.run(query))
  .map(MyCustomDTO(_))
  .toRight(dataNotFound())
  .value
```

The problem is with `.toRight`. I would like to map it to sifferent errors depends on what was returned by database. E.g.

```
case FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION.toString => constraintError()
case UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION.toString => uniqueError()
case _ => dataNotFound()
```

I tried to do `match case` in `.toRight()`, but it does not work:

```
.toRight(error => error.asInstanceOf[PSQLException].getSQLState match { .... })
```

I'm wondering what is the best possibility to map different errors here in a correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [the signature of `toRight(...)`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/main/core/src/main/scala/cats/data/OptionT.scala#L495)

```
def toRight[L](left: => L)(implicit F: Functor[F]): EitherT[F, L, A] =
  EitherT(cata(Left(left), Right.apply))
```

both of these take by-name parameter - on other words they are special syntax of `() => ...` where `() => ...` in definition and `...()` in application are inserted for you. Why? Because on `toLeft`/`toRight` in `OptionT` assume that you are handling the kind of error that is expresses by **`Option`** - that is `None`. Since there is no need to pass `_: None.type =>` it uses by-name parameter instead.

If you want to handle the error you have to handle it inside `F[A]` - by providing the right type class (`ApplicativeError[F, Throwable]`/`MonadError[F, Throwable]`) which would allow calling `handleError`/`handleErrorWith`/`redeem` etc

```
// F: ApplicativeError[F, Throwable]
// fa: F[MyCustomDTO]
F.redeem(fa)(a => Right(a), error => Left(error match { ... }))

// or with extension methods for AplicativeError
fa.redeem(a => Right(a), error => Left(error match { ... }))

// asRight is extension method creating Either
fa.map(_.asRight[Error]).handleError(e => Left(...))
```

since your `F` seem to be `Future`, and since you have it wrapped in `OptionT` I guess it worked better if you did something like:

```
OptionT(database.run(query))
  .map(MyCustomDTO(_).asRight[Error])
  .getOrElse(dataNotFound().asLeft[MyCustomDTO])
  .handleError { error =>
    Left(error.asInstanceOf[PSQLException].getSQLState match {
      ...
    })
  }
```

You could also give up on `OptionT` and do:

```
database.run(query).attemptT // EitherT[Future, Throwable, ...]
  .leftMap { error =>
    error.asInstanceOf[PSQLException].getSQLState match {
      ...
    }
  }
  .subflatMap { option =>
    option.fold(dataNotFound().asLeft)(MyCustomDTO(_).asRight))
  }
  .value
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me. Now I understand. One thing in your last example is it does not work ` option.fold(dataNotFound().asLeft)(MyCustomDTO(_).asRight))` and I needed to do `match case` on `Option` and return `Left(error)` and `Right(data)`. With `fold` there is compilation exception

Comment: You can try using type hints if inference doesn't work e.g. `option.fold(dataNotFound().asLeft[MyCustomDTO])(MyCustomDTO(_).asRight))` (assuming `dataNotFound()` returns `Error` and doesn't require upcasting) or `option.fold[Either[Error, MyCustomDTO]](dataNotFound().asLeft)(MyCustomDTO(_).asRight))`.